# Lotus form's Postopen coding change to Xpage

Tags: xpages

I have an application, there are some coding in the Lotus form's Postopen, now I need to change this client application to web with XPage.

How could I write coding in XPage to realize the form's Postopen function? Thanks for help!

Following is the form's Postopen coding:

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument)
.........
Set Targetdb = New NotesDatabase(db.Server, "OAS\PERSONAL.NSF")
Set enameview = Targetdb .GetView( "ENAMEVIEW" )
If enameview Is Nothing Then
    Print "Coludn't find ENAMEVIEW  View."
    Exit Sub
End If
Set cnameview = Targetdb .GetView( "CNAMEVIEW" )
If cnameview Is Nothing Then
    Print "Couldn't find CNAMEVIEW  View."
    Exit Sub
End If
Set Personaldoc = enameview.GetDocumentByKey(userName.ABBREVIATED,True)
If Personaldoc Is Nothing  Then
    message = "Couldn't find your information in Personal Database。 " &  Chr(10)
    msgtype = MB_OK + MB_ICONSTOP
    return_code = Messagebox (message, msgtype, db.Title)
    Exit Sub
End If
Set doc = Source.Document
If doc.IsNewNote Then
    doc.dept=Personaldoc.DEP_NO_CNAME(0)
    doc.Location = Personaldoc.Location(0)
    If Personaldoc.C_SUPERIOR2(0)="" Then
        doc.Director= Personaldoc.C_SUPERIOR(0)
    Else
        doc.Director= Personaldoc.C_SUPERIOR2(0)
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to insert the coding to this comment, but I don't know how to insert.

Comment: Update the question instead.

Comment: I have update the question, but I still not got the correct answer about how to write the Lotus Form's Postopen coding in XPage.

Comment: No people could help me? or give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Not very detailed, but you might want to look at the "afterRenderResponse" event of the page/custom control, and the postOpenDocument event of your data source.  The exact location of your code will depend on what you want to do, and this is where we need more inofrmation regarding what you are trying to achieve.

As an example, I have some code that adds to a counter each time a page is opened.  My code is located in the data source's postOpenDocument event, as I am using a LotusScript agent to do the job (the agent already existed, so I just needed to call it).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I want to realize the function is: When user click the "New Request" in the xpage view. I want to verify whether this user's information is in the other database(e.g.:Personal database), if so allow to create new xpage document. otherwise don't allow.

Comment: I woudl then create a page that is in fact an xAgent (you can get more info on searching Google for xAgent) that does the lookup for you and depending on the lookup result, redirect to a different page.  Another option is to have the lookup done on the "onChange"  or "onExit" of your form's user name by some SSJS function that might set a session scope variable, which would be used to show or hide different panels in your form, once the partial refresh has refreshed the page.

Comment: The Lotus Form's Postopen coding is only to verify whether the user who click the "New Request" button, his personal information is in the other database(e.g.:Personal database), and set the Form's several fields with the personal information.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your XPage in Designer, in the Outline window click on the XPage:
[image: XPage Outline]

Then in the Events window select the appropriate Event under Page depending if you want server side or client side actions with your data:
[image]